# Best way to Continuous deployment for Drupal 7 websites

Tags: drupal-7, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment

I tried many modules to deploy the changes from development to staging manually but didn't find the better way to deploy the changes either coding or database to the staging server automatically.

Is there anything for Drupal 7 by which I can push my changes from development to staging without any manual work? I want all database related configuration, codes etc to be pushed automatically on the live server.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways you can automate your deployment. one of which we follow is as below:

1. Using third party services like platform or pantheon for deployment.
2. Using hook_update_N along with features and strongram modules for configuration management.
3. Using shell script for running custom commands after deployment.
4. Using jenkins for deployment automation.

Some other tools / services can be found here https://www.kelltontech.com/monkey-talk

Comment: Thanks for the comment. But I don't understand how the Jenkins work to deploy the database changes as it only used for code deployment.

Comment: You dont need to worry about database changes. Just execute update.php or drush updb after code deployment and use drupal update hooks to work with database changes.